# python manage.py makemigrations : No changes detected

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am working on a project using django and I am using pycharm software. In my 'store' directory i have a python package called 'models' in which there are two python files :- **init**.py and `product.py` . The problem i am getting is that I cannot create table using the command  even when I am importing the 'Product' class from product module in **init**.py file. Even both the modules are also in the same package.
Here is the code of the product.py file:-

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
```

And here is the code of **init**.py file:-

```
from .product import Product
```

But when i am running the command on terminal i am getting this error:-

```
(venv) C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\SMart>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Comment: Is the app `store` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? What also helps sometimes is to specify the app as in `python manage.py makemigrations store`.

Comment: Have you added the store app name to the list of installed apps in your settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the name of your app <`store`> into the list of INSTALLED_APPS inside your settings.

Comment: yes as u said i have added the app name <store> INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'store']
like this but then too it is not detecting changes

Comment: in your store app, do you have the migrations directory? Does it have `__init__.py` inside it?

Comment: yes it does have migrations directory and __init__.py inside it. I dont know where it is going wrong

Comment: inside your `store` app, do you have the module `models.py`?

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, the error is resolved. Actually i didnt specified the app name while passing the command in terminal.

Comment: Often there's no need to explicitly pass the name of your app to `makemigrations` if it's properly set inside the installed apps. Glad it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Django 4. To solve it, I created `migrations/__init__.py` file in every app directory. So just run these command for every app:

```
mkdir appname/migrations
touch appname/migrations/__init__.py
```

Then use `manage.py`:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

And it worked.